# Utilizing multiple StringVar() variables in a list in Tkinter Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I am developing a way to store the StringVar() objects in a list, so when I have to update them, I can do it with a quick For loop, the issue is when I .grid() the labels, they all show the final value of the loop.  I would like to know how I can store and appropriate .set the StringVar variable for quick updating.
Thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
strVarLst = [StringVar()] * 5
labels = [None] * 5
def Main():
    print (strVarLst)
    print (len(strVarLst), len(labels))
    for i in range(5):
        a = str(i)
        strVarLst[i].set(a)
        labels[i] = Label(win, textvariable=strVarLst[i])
        print("i:", i, "\tstrVarLst[]:", strVarLst[i].get())
        labels[i].grid()
win.mainloop()
Main()
```

Comment: You don't have a list of multiple `StringVar()`s.  You have a list with 5 references to a single `StringVar()`.  You could initialize the list with `None`s, then create and assign `StringVar`s in the loop (exactly as you're currently doing with the `Label`s.  Or, you can initialize the list with `[StringVar() for _ in range(5)]` to create five distinct objects.

Comment: @jasonharper, You're absolutely correct!  Thanks, simple fix made all the difference.  I appreciate it!

Comment: If all you're doing is using it to update labels, you don't need the stringvars at all. Just loop over the list of labels instead of the list of variables. That will reduce the complexity of your code a little, since it's six fewer objects to maintain (the five stringvars plus the list to hold them).

Comment: @BryanOakley That's a good idea, in the actual program I am writing, I have 22 elements in each list, so that would help out, thanks!